# Getting gdb to work for this project

Tags: debugging, c++, c, gdb

For [this project](http://people.csail.mit.edu/kaess/apriltags/), I cannot seem to get `M-x gdb` to work in Emacs 25.1 (on Ubuntu 14.04.5 64-bit if it matters - this should be the case for any Ubuntu-based Linux in general I imagine). Steps to reproduce:

```
sudo apt-get install subversion cmake libopencv-dev libeigen3-dev libv4l-dev
cd ~/Downloads/
svn co https://svn.csail.mit.edu/apriltags
cd apriltags
make BUILD_TYPE=Debug
./build/bin/apriltags_demo # run program to see that it works
```

Now fire up Emacs and go to the file located in `examples/apriltags_demo.cpp` of the downloaded directory. Running `M-x gdb` and accepting the default `gdb -i=mi main` as the gdb command, I cannot place breakpoints anywhere by mouse clicking in the left fringe of the `gdb-many-windows` view - like I can do for any other simple program that I create and compile with `g++ -std=c++11 -g main.cpp -o main`.

Can you please try to reproduce my steps/explain how to get this to work? Thank you!

**Note**: using [realgud](https://github.com/realgud/realgud) works flawlessly - but I want to see why it doesn't work with Emacs' built-in GDB functionality.

Comment: Note: typing `M-x gdb` and then replacing the default command with `gdb -i=mi -s ../build/bin/apriltags_demo -e apriltags_demo -d ../../src -d ../../AprilTags` seems to do the trick. But is there a better way? For example, set this command to be the default for the project?